# How to dissect UDP msgpack using Wireshark/tshark?

Tags: wireshark, tshark, msgpack, wireshark-dissector

Since v3.0.0 Wireshark supports msgpack. I have a capture file containing msgpack messages encapsulated in UDP I want to dissect. The problem is that when I'm running:

```
tshark -r 1.pcap -d udp.port==60003,msgpack
```

I get following message:

```
tshark: Protocol "msgpack" isn't valid for layer type "udp.port"
tshark: Valid protocols for layer type "udp.port" are:
```

The list of supported protocol contains msgpack:

```
tshark -G protocols | grep msgpack
Message Pack    MsgPack msgpack
```

Here is the link to example capture file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qZO-WKgTValghMjC4kM56B-M1FlYg5C2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If msgpack has a port number like HTTP, then you would be able to use the `-d` decode-as flag. msgpack is a JSON alternative, so I'm guessing not. Can you provide a link to the packet capture containing the protocol?

Comment: Here is the link to example capture file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qZO-WKgTValghMjC4kM56B-M1FlYg5C2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I lied. You should be able to decode-as msgpack. This looks like a bug. I'll post an interim solution though VVV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to decode as msgpack in latest 3.07 tshark & Wireshark (i.e. this looks like a bug). If you are feeling virtuous, you can [file one](https://bugs.wireshark.org).

You can still access the data layer that comes after layer 4. We can use shell magic to do the equivalent of decoding the layer with the file you provided:

```sh
# Unix-like (Macos/Linux/BSD) systems ship with xxd.
# WSL on Windows will also have it.
bash$ tshark -r msgpack.pcap -T fields -e data | xxd -p -r | msgpack2json && echo
{"message_type":"complete_caching","generation":123992}
```

Here, we

- Print the data field with tshark as ASCII hex
- Use xxd to convert from text hex to bin hex
- Use `msgpack2json` from [msgpack-tools](https://github.com/ludocode/msgpack-tools) to convert the binary data back to JSON.